# two module-info.java in one package

Tags: java, module, package, java-9

I want to make work the project with two module inside one package.
There is package com.test which include  test1 and test2.
This code is note compile because:

Error:Multiple module-info files in module 'Java9Test'

What is not correct?

test1 contains module-info.java

```
module com.test.test1 {}
```

and Client.java

```
package com.test.test1;

import com.test.test2.Provider;

public Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Provider provider = new Provider();
        System.out.printf(provider.getString(), "TestA");
    }
}
```

and package test2 which contains

module-info.java

```
module com.test.test2 {}
```

and Provider.java

```
package com.test.test2;

public class Provider {
    public String getString(){
        return "Hello, %s!";
    }
}
```

Sorry but I very new in module with java9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler (or the IDE) thinks that you have just one module. One module can only have one module descriptor (`module-info.java`).

You could try the following directory structure:

```
module1/
  module-info.java
  com/
    test/
      test1/
        Client.java
module2/
  module-info.java
  com/
    test/
      test2/
        Provider.java
```

Each of the top-level `module1` and `module2` directories are module directories, so you would have 2 modules.

First module descriptor

```
module module1 {
    requires module2;
}
```

Second module descriptor

```
module module2 {
    exports com.test.test2;
}
```

Comment: There is an Error:java: Cannot compile a module cycle with multiple module-info.java files: module1, module2

Comment: @Petro What file structure do you have and how exactly do you compile your project?

Comment: I think ```module cycle``` not has treatment